# Tap event inside scrollview fires while scrolling

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

We have a scrollview and elements inside the scrollview have tap event.
When user puts his finger on an item inside scrollview and scrolls a tiny bit and releases it, the tap event fires. This is not a normal behavior and does not happen  in listviews.

```html
<ScrollView orientation="vertical" class="scrollView" sdkToggleNavButton>
  <StackLayout class="wrapper">
    <StackLayout class="slide" (tap)="openMembership();"></StackLayout>
    <StackLayout class="slide" (tap)="openMembership();"></StackLayout>
    <StackLayout class="slide" (tap)="openMembership();"></StackLayout>
    <StackLayout class="slide" (tap)="openMembership();"></StackLayout>
    <StackLayout class="slide" (tap)="openMembership();"></StackLayout>
    <StackLayout class="slide" (tap)="openMembership();"></StackLayout>
    <StackLayout class="slide" (tap)="openMembership();"></StackLayout>
  </StackLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

In the above example, the StackLayout with "slide" class's tap is fired while scrolling. (If the finger is moved more than like 15 pixels, it does not happen and it just happens in small scrolls)

I tested it in iOS only and I am not sure about android.

I was wondering what is the correct way to use taps inside scrollview to prevent this?

Comment: You could ignore the tap event when ScrollView is being scrolled.

Comment: How should I know the scrollview is being scrolled? Is there any flag I can check?

Comment: You may have to add pan event on scroll view and keep a local flag when it's being moved. Use that flag to avoid tap on child components.

Comment: Ok, I was able to achieve this using the following code:

`public onScroll(args) {
    this.scrolling = true;

    setTimeout(() => {
        this.scrolling = false;
    }, 300);
  }`

But I think this should be implemented in NativeScript's scrollview element that it does not propagate tap event to its children while scrolling